# MonoTouch GlassButton Aesthetics

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, uiglassbutton

I'd like to force the row that the GlassButton sits in to be far smaller.  I'd rather not make a button that stretches all of the way across a table considering that this is an iPad application.  How can I reduce the size of an individual row in MonoTouch.Dialog's elements api.  I'd like to make it look like a rather typical button.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for it is here:

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Utilities/GlassButton.cs

You can make the button smaller by passing a smaller rectangle.